# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm making a foreign key but I don't understand why it won't work

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.QLKeSach' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_QLKeSach_QLKeSach'.
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Like this:

```
create table QLKeSach
(
MaKeSach varchar(10) not null,
TenKeSach char(10) not null,
MaTang varchar(10) not null,
MaNgan varchar(10) not null,
MaKho varchar(10) not null,
)
```

```
create table QLTangSach
(
MaTang varchar(10) not null,
TenTang char(30) not null,
MaKeSach varchar(10) not null,
)
```

I created them but it gives an error

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.QLKeSach
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_QLKeSach
FOREIGN KEY (MaTang)
REFERENCES dbo.QLTangSach(MaTang);
```

Comment: You need to define a primary key if possible on the QLKeSach table.  The FK concept relies upon being able to find a single record, not a set of records, when looking for the related record.  There might be more than one set of columns that can be a primary key.  If a PK is already defined, consider a unique index on candidate keys.  With a PK, only on record can have a null value for the PK columns.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Correction.  PK cannot have null values.  A unique index can have nulls; however, nulls can be only exist uniquely.  For example, a single column unique index can't have two records with a null in that column.  For more columns, no two records can have the same combination of nulls and values.